# What model is this Dyno? Serial number makes it 1995 Nitro? VFR?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

All stamped Dyno, white chainwheel, forks, stem, and bars. Cant find another like it, wondering if parts may have been swapped out at some point because I cant find this colorway anywhere, the dropouts look like a Nitro or VFR but I dont know what it is. I looked all through the museum and the only other bike with comparable colors is a Dyno air but the frame is different.

[image: Dyno BMX unknown model]

Comment: Colors are irrelevant, could have changed several times, unless you had the bike since the manufacturing. Look for the features in the shape of things, although these generic BMX bikes look all the same to me.